# Microsoft Form to PDF using Power Automate

Tags: power-automate, microsoft-forms

I am currently trying to take a microsoft form submission and turn it into a pdf to email. I create a file as a pdf, get the file contents, and then I email. When I open the file on email it says "Something went wrong, Can't Open File". I do not know the issue, and any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are attaching the PDF to the email I am guessing there would be an issue while assigning the value of file content in the email action, I can be more helpful if you can provide some more details or a screen shot of the flow.

Regards
RT